# Is there a way to check when threading.Timer will run?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say I have the following python3 program:

```
from threading import Timer
import time

thread = Timer(600, print, args=['I am running'])
thread.start()

while threading.activeCount() > 1:
    {{Function to calculate time until thread will start running}}
    print ("Thread will start in %d seconds" % {get above value})
    time.sleep(10)
```

What I'm looking at is a little more complex, with multiple threads, but essentially, for a given Timer thread, is there any way to inspect it to see when it is scheduled to run?

Comment: Do you the pool of threads?

Comment: No...I just get all the open threads with threading.enumerate().

Comment: is't a bad practice to use many threads without pool.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I'm getting what you say right, but you may want something like that:

```
from threading import Thread
import time

thread = Timer(600, print, args=['I am running'])
thread.start()

class ThreadTimeoutLauncher(Thread):
    def __init__(self, timeout, cb, *args, **kwarg):
        super(Thread, self).__init__()
        self.timeout = timeout
        self._cb = cb
        self._args = args
        self._kwarg = kwarg

    def run():
        print ("Thread will start in %d seconds" % self.timeout)
        while self.timeout > 0:
            time.sleep(1)
            self.timeout -= 1
        self.cb(*self._args, **self._kwarg)
```

the idea here, is to recreate a Timer thread that will count down until the time is out, and updates the "timeout value" while doing so. When it's over it launches the Thread event. So when you do:

```
def foo():
    print "Thread launched!"

t = ThreadTimeoutLauncher(600, foo)
t.start()
while True:
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print "thread will be launched in: %d sec." % t.timeout
```

It may also be possible to inherit from Timer and change the run() method of Timer, but it'd mean to *UTSL* ;-)

Comment: I ended up implementing something along this line, but instead I wrapped everything up in a dictionary (pseudo code): {startTime: 2030-10-10 05:00:00, thread: Timer(seconds_til_start_time, function_to_run)}.